# Lotus Notes 8.5 - How do I alter the FROM value in the headers of my outbound emails?

Tags: email, ibm-domino, lotus-notes, smtp-headers

I'm running a Lotus Notes 8.5 client (through a domino server). I have a really ugly FROM value in the header of my outbound emails:

```
firstname.lastname@company.com
```

I want a nice neat

```
"Firstname Lastname" <firstname.lastname@company.com>
```

How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the field you're trying to alter? Need to clarify exactly which area it is. Some of the fields are specifically there for message routing, so they can't be altered.

Comment: Here's a sample of the email header that is getting sent with my emails: From: firstname.lastname@company.com

Comment: I don't know which field I need to alter.

Comment: are you the domino administrator, if not then you probably won't be able to make the change!  And from the sounds of it your not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this needs to be set by your Domino Administrator - you can't fix it from the client. I can't see why this would deliberately not be set though, so you could suggest to your admin (politely!) that they make the change.

The setting is in the Server Configuration Document, under MIME, Advanced, Outbound Message Options, RFC822 phrase handling. They probably want to "Use CN as phrase", which would normally give the "Firstname Lastname"  that you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks Adam. If I contact our IT support team and make this request, will it affect all users, or just me?

Comment: It will affect all users on that server - definitely an "IT department decision" that they'll need to make